# Excel VBA: For Each loop returning Values not Ranges

Tags: vba, excel, foreach, excel-2013

I'm trying to use a `For Each` loop to check two ranges of cells against each other, looking for matching values.

My problem is that the `For Each` loops seems to be iterating over the values of the cells (i.e John Doe, Mark Jones, etc.) and not the range values (i.e D3, D4, etc.). This seems counter to all the documentation I've read.

```
lastRowRads = Worksheets("Rads").Range("D3").End(xlDown).Row
lastRowData = Worksheets("Data").Range("D5").End(xlDown).Row
ReferenceRange = "D5:D" & lastRowData
TestRange = "D3:D" & lastRowRads
For Each rcell In Worksheets("Data").Range(ReferenceRange).Cells
    For Each tcell In Worksheets("Rads").Range(TestRange).Cells
        If rcell.Value = tcell.Value Then
           Worksheets("Data").Range(rcell).Offset(0, -1).Value = Worksheets("Rads").Range(tcell).Value
        End If
    Next tcell
Next rcell
```

The error I get is "Run-time error '1004: Application-define or object-defined error" and the debugger highlights the statement within the `If...Then` statement. My guess was that it wasn't accepting the `rcell` and `tcell` as range references.

I've done some troubleshooting using `MsgBox` to see what the values of the `tcell` and `rcell` are as they go through the loop and they're what should be `rcell.Value` and `tcell.Value`. I've tried defining them as `Dim tcell As Range` and `Dim rcell As Range` prior to the loop, but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Change this line `Worksheets("Data").Range(rcell).Offset(0, -1).Value = Worksheets("Rads").Range(tcell).Value` to `rcell.Offset(0, -1).Value = tcell.Value`  They are range variable and thus already have the sheet and range inherent in them.

Comment: @Fadi put your answer back.  It still is a good answer, just make sure you declare the variables properly.

Comment: @ScottCraner, `lastRowData` and `ReferenceRange` are address not range as i thought, so my answer is not correct, i think we just need to use `rcell.Offset(0, -1).Value = tcell.Value` as your comment.

Comment: That was the problem. Removing the beginning of each of those allowed the sub to run correctly. If you want to put that as answer, I can set it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
Worksheets("Data").Range(rcell).Offset(0, -1).Value = Worksheets("Rads").Range(tcell).Value
```

To:

```
rcell.Offset(0, -1).Value = tcell.Value
```

They are range variables and thus already have the sheet and range inherent in them.

Comment: Thank you for your help!